# How can I get a variable from one function to another in Kotlin

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

How can I make a local variable in Kotlin accessible in another function? In python you can use `global` to make a variable accessible everywhere. What is the equivalent of that in Kotlin?

This is my code:

```
fun add(){
    val a: Int = 3
    val b: Int = 5
    val c: Int = a + b
}

fun multiply(value: Int){
    println(value * 5)
}
```

How can I pass variable `c` as a parameter for the `multiply` function so that it would run like
`multiply(c)`. From what I've understood, `c` is a local variable and can only be accessed in the `add` function. How can I make it a global scope variable?

Comment: This is a code smell when it comes to primitive types such as int, str and chars. You're better off returning the value from function and storing it where you want it.

Answer (score 3):

You have to initialize the variable outside of the function.

```
var x = 100

fun fn() { 
 x = x + 100 
}
```